# Build Instructions for Brown Fedora Hat at LEGOLAND Florida Resort Hotel

Tags: design, legoland

When visiting LEGOLAND Florida, I fell in love with this brown Fedora hat that was in the bathroom of our suite at the resort.

I am not familiar with the custom LEGO building community and don't even know where to look for build instructions for something like this, or how to begin figuring out how to build it.

Might someone here be able go get me started?

[image: LEGO Adventurer Hat]

Comment: I think it unlikely there will be building instructions for this. Stuff like this is created by legoland staff or profesionals who will protect their designs.
I think your best bet is trying to create this from the picture, it's detailed enough.
You'll need to know how to get bricks cheap, see other bricks.stackexchange questions for that.
Alternatively, you could try to find an STL file online of a fedora hat and use brickify (https://brickify.it/) to generate lego instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
Hey Victor, I bring gifts!

This *LEGO Digital Draw* file should get you started, as you've asked.

[image]

Please consider this a rough draft of your Brown Fedora.  I'm calling it rough, because at this early stage, it was just made to look as close to the actual picture with no care for a sensible design flow.

For example, the file may have three stacked 1x4 plates, where there should be a 1x4 brick or corner piece there instead. The abundant plates were used to  guesstimate height levels, and left in place because due to the lack of reference material, every level may not be correct.

So, with the *[LDD program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UMBmH7OkOuGcLucUxVVBoKN-1dTVAThH)*, it is possible to generate build instructions, but again, the design flow will not make sense until more data is collected from the field.

**What You're Getting:**

- A *[**link to my Google Drive folder**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UMBmH7OkOuGcLucUxVVBoKN-1dTVAThH)* that contains the LDD file (*.lxf), and all my collected reference material of pictures and videos.  Anyone is welcome to add their two brick clicks to this build.

**Notes and Issues:**

- **From What I Understand:** LEGOLAND Resort is a hotel, outside but within some walking distance to an actual LEGOLAND theme park.  So, no one is actually squatting inside the park;).

  Hotel guests spend the night in a LEGO themed hotel room.  The 5
  Themes if available at a particular hotel are: *Ninjago*, *Pirate*, *LEGO
  Friends*, *Kingdom*, and *Adventure*.

  [image]
- **Field Research / Resort Locations**: There are multiple LEGOLAND resorts, and it seems like I've traveled the world to find videos and
  shots of this hat.

  So far, only hotels Florida and Malaysia have our brown hat, all
  other resorts I've searched, California, Windsor, UK, Germany, Japan,
  and Dubai, all have a gray hat with a totally different design (and clearer pictures).
- **Build Discrepancies Between Images**: Reference images for the top of the hat seems to be missing pieces, or pieces seem to be shifted between images/rooms. One reason I could come up with to explain the discrepancy is a hotel guest pawing the hats, and oops a piece comes off, then it gets reassemble wrong.
- **Lucky Mirror Shortcuting:** We lucked out with the hat being symmetrical (*Sort of), which means we got away with building half, and just mirrored out the rest. Less work, Yay!
- **(*Sort of) Symmetry Explained**. You'll notice in some images and shots that the left side of the tan band of the hat lumps out for no
  apparent reason.  [image]

  So,I google imaged Fedora hats, and you'll see some of them sport overlapping material pinned down with a swanky feather.

  [image]

  So, I think the designer built the staging for a type of hat
  accessory.
- **Need more data (01)**. I have no great shots of how the hat connects to the tan mounting block, the actual size of the mounting block, nor how flush the entire piece hugs up on the wall.
- **Need more data (02)**. I have no idea if the designer scooped out the underside of the hat that no guest would ever see, unless some crazy curious guest pulled it off the wall to properly check underneath.

**What Next?**

So, basically the next step to finalizing some great build instructions is to collect more field material.

---

**TO ALL FUTURE HOTEL GUESTS OF ANY LEGOLAND THEMED RESORT HOTEL.**

Hey, please share your family's visit to any of these hotels.  We'd like to experience through you, the fun times in your room at a LEGOLAND Resort.

It would be great if we knew:

1. Which Country?:
2. What City?:
3. Which room theme you picked?:
4. What suite number You stayed in?:(Room comparison to control for build discrepancies.)
5. Name of the sculptured object you plan to share with the community?.

[image]

We can near replicate anything you've seen, but the level of replication depends on how detailed your pictures/videos are.

- Hold your camera horizontal please (for the rest of my *cough forsaken cough* life);).[image]
- A non shaky, slow paced 360 closeup video of any design would be
  ideal.
- If you happen to have a loose off colored brick on hand, stick that
  on it too. Doing so would help out when determining level height.